# How to find the index of a node based on the weight of the node in a binary search tree?

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a method that when you are given an index and you have to return the node at that given index from a binary search tree. You have to recursively call the method and return  the node at that index. We have a  size variable that holds the number of nodes below that node. But, I just can't figure out the logic behind finding the index of a node based on the size variable.

Comment: First, we'll need to see the code for your binary search tree.

Comment: What if the size variable of the child nodes told you there were 10 elements in the left subtree and 8 in the right subtree?  Would that help?